# Existe uma forma melhor de se remover um elemento de um array em JS no ponto de vista de programação funcional?

Tags: javascript

Estava tentando remover um elemento de um array, e uma vez que estou tentando aprender um pouco mais sobre programação funcional, tentei mudar a velha forma que eu utilizava para fazer isto.

```js
const myArray = [
  {id: 1, label: 'first'},
  {id: 2, label: 'second'},
  {id: 3, label: 'third'},
]

const itemToRemove = {
 id: 2,
  label: 'second'
}

myArray.splice(myArray.findIndex(item => {
 return item.id == itemToRemove.id
}), 1)

console.log('->', JSON.stringify(myArray, null, 2))
```

Minha dúvida...
Existe uma forma melhor de juntar (chain) estas duas funções?
Existe uma forma melhor de fazer isto (no ponto de vista de programação funcional)?

Muito obrigado.

Comment: quais são as duas funções que queres juntar ? splice e findIndex ?

Comment: Exato, ou ao menos era a ideia inicial (antes da consideração do @sergio)

Answer (score 1):

Um dos paradigmas da programação funcional é não mudar dados fora de uma dada função. Ou seja ter estruturas imutáveis e funções puras. O `splice` vai na direção oposta e muda uma array, sem criar uma cópia. E isso pode ter consequências indesejadas.

Para filtrar elementos de uma array com princípios de programação funcional deve usar-se o `.filter` e criar outra array, ou se fôr desejado sobre-escrever a variável. Em ambos os casos a array original fica inalterada.

```js
const myArray = [
  {id: 1, label: 'first'},
  {id: 2, label: 'second'},
  {id: 3, label: 'third'},
]

const itemToRemove = {
 id: 2,
  label: 'second'
}

// comparando os objetos transformados em string
const filtrada1 = myArray.filter(
    el => JSON.stringify(el) != JSON.stringify(itemToRemove)
);
console.log(1, JSON.stringify(filtrada1));

// se bastar comparar com o `id`
const filtrada2 = myArray.filter(
    ({id}) => id != itemToRemove.id
);
console.log(2, JSON.stringify(filtrada2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que esta seria a resposta ideal se estas a procura de **simplicidade** e programação funcional,
utilizando a função **[grep()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/)**:

```js
var obj =  [ {id: "1", name: "Ola"}, 
            {id: "2", name: "Java"}, 
            {id: "3", name: "Script"}];
obj = $.grep(obj , function (value) {
        return value.id != '1';
});

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Exemplo de Syntax:

```
retorno = $.grep(ObjetoASerRemovido, function (value) {
        // aqui pode ser a condição que preferires ex: value.name != 'Ola' && value.id != '1'
        return value.id != '1';
});
```